# Stuck in present day cave without all the power sources

Tags: assassins-creed-3

How do I get out of present day when I've only gotten 1 power source? I'm stuck in the cave and nothing happens when I walk up to the second power source on the ledge. I am trying to go back to being Connor, but I can't.

Answer (score 7):

You need to walk up the the Animus and press any button to re-enter it and become Conner again. The Animus is located across from your laptop, near Rebecca Crane.