# Where are the sockets for the power sources?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I've been walking around this cave forever and I can't find the socket for the power source from the skyscraper.

Where are the sockets for the power sources in Assassins Creed 3?

Comment: Related, perhaps? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/92538/stuck-in-present-day-cave-without-all-the-power-sources

Comment: @fbueckert Nope. Not at all, from what I can tell.

Comment: Huh.  They sound similar.  Alrighty, then.

Answer (score 2):

The sockets are on balconies up high above the main room where the Animus and your Assassin buddies hang out. If you look sometimes you can see Juno pacing on the balconies. They're essentially climbing puzzles. When you get up to the balcony you'll see something that looks a little like a control console, you'll get a quick cutscene showing you placing the power source. IIRC they're only accessible after you get the power sources and a door slides open.

If you want a more spoilerish answer, [this guide is pretty good](http://www.gamersheroes.com/assassins-creed-3-guide-placing-the-power-sources).